# Checkboxes list - shared prefrences

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I want to create a list of checkboxes, these checkboxes are generated dynamically from a table in a database the code may looks like :

```
    public void getCategories(Context context) {

    Quote quote_instance = new Quote();
    final ArrayList<Quote> allQuotesObjects = quote_instance
            .getAllObjectsForField(context, "Category");
    categories_items = new String[allQuotesObjects.size() - 1];
    final boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[categories_items.length];
    for (int x = 0; x < allQuotesObjects.size() - 1; x++) {
        categories_items[x] = allQuotesObjects.get(x).Category;
    }
    cat_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(categories_items));
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(
            R.string.category_widget_label));
    builder.setPositiveButton("Select",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < categories_items.length; i++) {
                        if (itemsChecked[i]) {
                            categories_ids.add(i);
                        } else if (categories_ids.contains(i)) {
                            categories_ids.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
//  Log.i("AHMAD", cat_list.toString());

    boolean[] prechecked = new boolean[categories_items.length];
    Arrays.fill(prechecked, true);
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(categories_items, prechecked,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    itemsChecked[which] = isChecked;
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}
```

It should look like this pic
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc9UR.png
(Sorry can't post images yet)

I can't make a checkbox for every item as they are generated pragmatically.
How to make this list using shared preferences ?

Comment: How are you currently making your `dialog`?

Comment: @mattblang I updated the question now with the full code

Comment: You can dynamically create a `View`, add a variable number of `Checkbox` objects to it, and set that view to the `AlertDialog.Builder` using `setView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do a for loop over the size of how many you need and then call:

```
Checkbox cb = new Checkbox(getApplicationContext());
cb.(add attributes)
layout.addView(cb)
```

Comment: How then I can recall the state of every checkbox using shared preferences ?

Comment: I think you need to re-think your design. Settings (which use shared preferences) really shouldn't be dynamic. You should try handling this in another `Activity` or `Fragment` and then pass the values back to the `Activity` that uses them

Comment: @AhmadEl-Melegy I agree with rsay3.  Maybe you could give us some more information on what you are trying to do this for?

Comment: Thanks guys I would go with your advice.@rsay3 I accepted your answer, but unfortunately I can't vote up yet.